# Is there a verb for "doing the wrong thing by force of habit"

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes find myself doing something I did not intend, just because the force of habit is so strong.   For instance: On the way back from work, turning toward home instead of the grocery store, even though I was planning on doing the shopping.  Or tossing the newspaper in the recycling bin right after my wife asked me to save an article for her.

Is there a verb for this behavior? As in "Sorry, I just {screwed up by habit}."

Comment: While it's not a verb, I most often just say something along the lines of "Sorry, force of habit." I haven't been misunderstood yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an idiom used in the US **[on autopilot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+autopilot)** (or *on automatic pilot*) meaning

> you do something without thinking about what you are doing, usually because you have done it many times before: *By the second week of the election campaign she was making all her speeches on automatic pilot*.

While not a verb in itself, you could say

> I was *on autopilot.*

Comment: +1 Also evident in Br.Eng. too.

Comment: "On autopilot" doesn't inherently imply doing something "wrong".

Comment: Kiorrik's comment is an important detail -- this can be used to explain that something you did wrong was due to habit, but you do have to say that you did something wrong.

Comment: @Kiorrik I agree in principle, but unless something has gone wrong (or is at least being done without a reasonable amount of diligence) the term probably would not be used.

Comment: I think it needs to be combined with `recidivist` to give it a sense of bad e.g. mild recidivist on autopilot .. or something like that.

Comment: @bib I disagree. "Oh, that's easy, I do that on autopilot", "you should be able to do that on autopilot", etc, can come up with plenty of cases. That said, prefacing with "Sorry" kind of implies a mistake has been made.

Comment: @Kiorrik, to me, ‘autopilot’ has a definite negative twang to it. I would never say something like, “Oh, that’s easy, I do that on autopilot”, ’cause ‘autopilot’ to me implies doing something thoughtlessly _when you should have been paying attention_. For your examples, I’d say, “Oh, that’s easy, I can do that in my sleep/with my eyes closed” instead, which implies doing something without thinking because there’s no need to think, rather than accidentally not thinking about something you really _should_ think about.

Comment: @user13107, adding ‘recidivist’ would make it sound like you’re actually committing crimes because you forget to stop and think that maybe you shouldn’t be. ‘Recidivist on autopilot’ sounds _very_ bizarre to me—like a newspaper heading about someone who’d been caught for the 39th time breaking into a house the exact same way as the other 38 times he got caught.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, you could say you were "acting by reflex" as in the automatic reflexes our bodies make (eg. knee-jerk). "Reflexing" comes to mind, but that's non-standard and awkward-sounding.

"Sorry, knee-jerk" is a phrase I could see myself adopting.

Answer (score -1):

"Guilty pleasure" or a form of "vicious" are the ones, that imply doing something

1. wrong,
2. by force of habit.

Other than that, the situation of tossing the newspaper into the bin is not vicious per se, but could become so, if you do it daily and your wife wants to have cut out something before daily...

All together: I do not think there is something that combines "autopilot" (which does not mean by force of habit implicitly, but doing something without thinking / "in trance") with wrong, except these two.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice